# Maximum length for cron job

Tags: curl, ssh, cron

I want to execute a command every minute (SSH). The command is a cURL bash, the length is 1625. When I put in the command in the crontabs and save:

```
    "/tmp/crontab.ijKPl1/crontab":51: command too long
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n)
```

Comment: It is likely you have a character in your cron command which has a special meaning in crontab. Try putting the command in a bash file, and executing the bash file instead.

Comment: You're probably better off asking this at [unix.se] instead. This site is  for programming related questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone on serverfault answered a similar question - [Crontab maximum command length](https://serverfault.com/questions/546342/crontab-maximum-command-length)

999 characters.

Just create a bash script and run it instead of having the entire command in crontab.

Comment: Hi. I have a shell script that will update the crontab for a user, however, I am getting the error as crontab is too long; maximum number of lines is 1000. Will the number of lines in the crontab really matter. ON debian and ubuntu 20 version I am not facing this issue. Only on ubuntu 18 this issue is experienced

Comment: @user11549576 Is it the same issue? If so - like I suggested, move the contents of the cron commands to a separate file and invoke it.
If not - please add more details (probably best in a new question)

Comment: I have created a separate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72216102/crontab-is-too-long-maximum-number-of-lines-is-1000 .When I add only 999 line in the crontab I am able to install the crontab for that user . Are there any limits for the crontab file in ubuntu ? As per your suggestion I moved the contents of the crontab file to a separate shell file and ran that file, but it gives me the error as command not found due to spaces in the file

Comment: Yes, it is the same issue. I created another shell file and added the contents of the crontab to that file and then ran the shell file.