# crontab is too long; maximum number of lines is 1000

Tags: cron

crons not running due to the issue on the crontab file for a user. I have shell script that will update the crontab for a user. However, currently running that shell script is giving me the following error The issue is experienced only on ubuntu 18.04 version. Other Debian 10, 11, ubuntu 20 machines are working fine with the same crontab

```
crontab is too long; maximum number of lines is 1000
```

I am not sure what is causing the issue. Could someone please help

Comment: Could you please upload (some of) your cron file?
There's no obvious reason for having such a long file.

Comment: It is a long list and it is running on one of the production server. Same cron file is working fine on debian 10, 11 and ubuntu version 20. Issue is experienced only on ubuntu version 18

Comment: crosspost: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408308/crontab-is-not-running-if-the-entries-are-more-than-1000 and answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/509298/is-it-possible-to-a-crontab-file-containing-1k-lines-of-schedules